# why my console shows 4 outputs in react.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, visual-web-developer

This is the output
[image]

This is my code I am fetching api
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Use are using `useEffect` wrong. The return function is supposed to run _after_ your component **unmounts**. You also mutate state in the unmount stage, which you are not supposed to do

Answer (score 2):

So what's happening is that since your data is stored in a state, initially on load, your data is empty, and you are logging that to the console. That is responsible for the first 2 *empty* outputs to the console (twice because you're in development mode aka Strict mode as you can see in your index.js your App is most likely wrapped in a strict mode).
The second set of identical outputs to the log are resulting after you asynch code successfully return and populates your data state with fresh info, and yet again logging twice for the same reason.